# Android Studio - Identify where threads are being created

Tags: android, multithreading

I am fairly new to using Android Studio. I just started on a team project. In our project we have identified that every time we disconnect and reconnect to a peripheral, we add a bunch of new/duplicate threads and we believe this eventually leads to an Android Not Responding condition. It seems that we are not properly shutting down the threads when we disconnect, and then we just recreate them when we connect again.

I have been using the Profiler in Android Studio to monitor the threads, and I have successfully been able to cut the number of new threads down from 20 to about 8, but I can't figure out where the other threads are being created. In the Profiler, I can see a list of the running threads. Most of them appear to be idle.

Is there a way to see where these threads are being created? Or is there a way to have a conditional breakpoint that stops when new threads are created?

[image]